# Save matches on array

Tags: python, regex

I've got stuck on a problem where I need to check an expression like module name(a, b, c, d) and save those variables to an array. This is where i got so far:

```
/^module\s(?P<module_name>\w+)(\s?)\(((\s?)((?P<module_params>\w+)\,)?)+(? P<module_last_param>\w+)\)$/
```

The output using the method match.groupdict() is:

```
{'module_params': 'b', 'module_name': 'hi', 'module_last_param': 'c'}
```

And when using match.groups():

```
('hi', '', '', '', 'b,', 'b', 'c')
```

When running this example:

```
module hi(a, b, c)
```

But the problem is, the value for module_params is being replaced apparently, and i need all of them to be saved on an array.

Comment: What would be the correct/desired *output* for that example?

Comment: I would like something like {'module_params': ['a', 'b'], 'module_name': 'hi', 'module_last_param': 'c'}, however I guess it isn't possible, then {'module_params_1': 'a', 'module_params_2': 'b', 'module_name': 'hi', 'module_last_param': 'c'} is good, how do you think I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use regexes, try this:

```
s = 'module hi(a, b, c)'
regex = re.compile(r'\s(\w+)\(([^\)]+)\)')
try:
    module_name, parameters = regex.search(s).groups()
except AttributeError as e:
    print 'No match for: {}'.format(s)
    raise
parameters = parameters.split(',')
print module_name, parameters
d = {'module_name':module_name,
     'module_params':parameters[:-1],
     'module_last_param':parameters[-1]}
print d
# {'module_last_param': ' c', 'module_name': 'hi', 'module_params': ['a', ' b']}
```

If you are confident that all of your data conforms to the pattern, you can also do this without regexes:

```
name, params = s.split('(')
name = name.split()[1]
params = params[:-1].split(',')
d = {'module_name':name,
     'module_params':params[:-1],
     'module_last_param':params[-1]}
```

Comment: ty, I was trying figure out a way using just the first regex, however, it looks impossible then I'll check it using my first regex and use split as you have suggested to extract the parameters once the priority is verify the pattern.

Comment: You can play around here, https://www.debuggex.com/, if you want to make your original work - best to keep it as simple as possible tho.